# How do these user/userParam references relate to the Customer and Account lookups?

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo

In [the following code example](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions.html) how do the `user/userParam` references relate to the `Customer` and `Account` lookups and what is the relationship between `Customer` and `Account`?

```
    // PersistenceManager pm = ...;
    Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();
    User user = userService.currentUser();
    List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();

    try {
        tx.begin();

        Query query = pm.newQuery("select from Customer " +
                                  "where user == userParam " +
                                  "parameters User userParam");
        List<Customer> customers = (List<Customer>)
        query.execute(user);

        query = pm.newQuery("select from Account " +
                            "where parent-pk == keyParam " +
                            "parameters Key keyParam");
        for (Customer customer : customers) {
            accounts.addAll((List<Account>)
            query.execute(customer.key));
        }

    } finally {
        if (tx.isActive()) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first query is querying all Customers `where Customer.user == userParam`.  So it looks like Customers have a one-to-one relationship with Users (presumably this is the GAE User class).

The second query is querying all Accounts where the account's parent-key is the key of a customer.  So it looks like Customers have a parent-child relationship with Accounts.

Putting it all together, every User has one Customer, and every Customer can have multiple child Accounts.  An Account can only have one parent Customer.